# Is there a way to use the mailto: or message: scheme in a PWA in iOS 12.2?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, url-scheme, ios12

I've built a PWA using Ionic 4 that had a "Contact" Button with a simple href using the 'mailto:' scheme.

```
<a href="mailto:example@gmail.com">Contact</a>
```

This used to open the native Mail app in iOS 12.1 when starting the PWA from homescreen. Since I updated to iOS 12.2 it just opens the PWA internal Safari with a message that Safari can't open links starting with 'mailto:'

I have tried using other URI schemes like 'instagram:' or 'message:' but they all lead to the same problem. The only one that I have found to still be functional when I start my PWA from homescreen is the 'tel:' scheme.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and has any idea how to still open URI schemes other than tel: from a PWA that has been opened from homescreen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it working using the below click function. 
Tested on both Android and iOS PWA.

```
()=>{
    window.location.href = "mailto:support@example.com?subject=" + emailSubject + "&body=" + emailBody
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a PWA which is installed on iOS 12.2, my link uses target="_blank" and it works.
Did you try this ?

Have a nice day,

Comment: I just tried this and I can confirm that it partly works. It does not work on a button, but with a simple <a> tag it opens the native Mail app. 

However, when I do this I am stuck in an empty browser page whenever I open my PWA, which I can not get out of unless I remove it from the home screen and add it again. Do you have any pointers on how you implemented it to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction, so I'll accept it as the correct answer.

When I add a click function using window.location.href it works just like before updating to iOS 12.2.
`window.location.href = 'mailto:example@gmail.com';`
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tobias, I have a similar issue and am not able to figure out how to get rid of the stale white screen. What was your solution?

Comment: Figured it out, just had to add a return at the end of the click function. Adding a new answer as target="_blank" is not a solution.