# iOS PWA special mailto link opens tab inside pwa browser. And stuck at blank tab

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

The mailto link was working as expected on previous versions of iOS. After updating to 12.2+ when opening default mail app using the mailto link the mail app works. But when coming back to the PWA, the application stuck on a blank white screen due to the iOS feature update to PWA (saving app state when switching apps)

Now i'm stuck with a blank screen even after swipe close the app.

I'm using the following code to lunch the mail app

```
<a href="mailto:example@example.com" target="_blank">send mail</a>
```

I have tried all other options of targets, **only the _blank target opens the default mail app**. Other targets are not working as mentioned in this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610036/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-mailto-or-message-scheme-in-a-pwa-in-ios-12-2).

Here is the screenshot of how the blank screen looks after coming back from mail app
[image: Blank Screen after coming back from mail app]

have anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use the mailto: or message: scheme in a PWA in iOS 12.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610036/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-mailto-or-message-scheme-in-a-pwa-in-ios-12-2)

Comment: @ViktorGardart it is not a duplicate, There the mail functionality itself not working. Here mail functionality is working fine, but the pwa stuck with a blank screen when going back to the pwa. I'm asking about the blank screen.

Also i mentioned that i used _blank as target

Comment: have you tried to use window.open to launch the mail app instead of href? PWA should display 'Done' button when opening external links. iOS seems to work this way more consistently than using href in <a> tags.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Rony I tried, but unfortunately this behavior is not accepted according to project specification.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the following solution in my own PWA and it works great (iOS 12.3.1, iPhone 7+)!

On your PWA page, you create the link as following:

```
<a onclick="sendFeedback()">Send Mail</a>
```

And you define this function:

```
function sendFeedback(e)
{   
    window.location.href = "mailto:example@example.com";   
}
```

Once clicked, it launches the default mail app. When you go back to your PWA, you will land on the page where the link is located. There won't be a blank screen.